# Is it a bad idea to pass an HttpRequest Object as a parameter to other objects methods?

Tags: java, httprequest

Is it a bad behavior to pass Http Request Object as a parameter to other class on Java?

Comment: Did you mean _to pass_? Also, no it is not.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis can you elaborate a little bit? If I were to pass the Request Object to a java bean's method you would not consider this bad practice?

Answer (score 5):

### Terrible Practice:

It tightly couples you to the `Servlet` Interface in all the code that accepts that as a parameter first off this *makes testing outside a `Servlet` container impossible*.

This is just one example of many terrible side effects that coupling like this causes.

> I have worked on plenty of legacy applications written by naive
>   developers that pass an reference of a `Servlet` interfaces like this
>   `Request` and `Response` all the way down to the database layer, and
>   use it as a global `god` object, nightmare of side effects and
>   dependencies!

Comment: I agree - there's no good reason to pass that object out of the web tier.  You should be validating and binding to business objects.

Comment: What do you mean "you should be validating and binding to business objects"? Do you mean that it is ok to pass the Request Object to business objects for the purpose of validation?